# How to Get Some div id With If Else in PHP

Tags: php

I want to ask about how to change div id in if else condition?
My code

```
<html>
    <div id="div1">
            <?php
            $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "";
            $page2 = isset($_GET['page2]) ? $_GET['page2] : "";
    if ($page == "If1") {
                include ".../some.php";
    
    }else if ($page2 == "If2") {
                echo '<div id="div2">';
                include ".../some2.php";
                echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</div>
</html>
```

if im going to page in https://localhost/index.php?page2=If2 i want change <div id="div1> to <div id="div2>
can i get some solution?
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach for doing that, using the `If-else` statement before printing the `<div ... >`

```
<html>
    <?php
       $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "";
       $page2 = isset($_GET['page2']) ? $_GET['page2'] : "";
    if ($page == "If1") {
       echo '<div id="div1">';
    }else if ($page2 == "If2") {
       echo '<div id="div2">
    }
    include ".../";
    ?>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Declare variable as html attribute

Declare your variable as a html attribute and assign it via php to your `<div>`.

```php
<?php
// check if request method is "get"
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
  if (isset($_GET['page'])) { // if "page"
    $divId = 'id="div1"';
  } else if (isset($_GET['page2'])) { // if "page2"
    $divId = 'id="div2"';
  }
}
?>
<html>
  <div <?php echo $divId ?>>
  <?php include ".../" ?>
  </div>
</html>
```

If you'd like to play around with my code in the browser directly, you can do so [here](https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalBountifulLibrary#index.php).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the simple answer**

```
<html>

  <div id="<?php echo isset($_GET['page2']) && $_GET['page'] == 'IF2' ? 'div2' : 'div1' ?>" >
    <!-- rest content -->
  </div>

</html>
```

**OR**

```
<html>
   <?php $id = isset($_GET['page2']) && $_GET['page'] == 'IF2' ? 'div2' : 'div1' ; ?>
  
   <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <!-- rest content -->
   </div>
</html>
```

***Note:*** You can also use PHP short_open_tag to echo id `<?= $id; ?>` . If short_open_tag  enable in php.ini in server

Comment: It is simple but confusing and unmaintainable in my opinion.

Comment: this code is confusing for who has to lack knowledge of ternary,
It doesn't break anything, how it's unmaintainable?